# Java FX LineChart of Objects

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I have an Object `DataEntry` defined as follows:

```
public class DataEntry {

private long timestamp;
private double value;

public DataEntry(long timestamp, double value) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.value = value;
}

public long getTimeStamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public double getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

I want to produce a `LineChart` of these elements with the timestamps in X and the values in Y. But I can't find on the Internet any tutorial about this (maybe I'm trying to do something impossible).

The best case for me would be a `LineChart` constructor which take an `ArrayList` of `DataEntry` as a parameter, because I want to integrate this chart to a scene.

Following is how far I came, but I can't execute my program.

```
public class DataEntryChart extends Application {

private String title;
private ArrayList<DataEntry> entries;

public DataEntryChart(String title, ArrayList<DataEntry> entries){
    this.title=title;
    this.entries=entries;
}

@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle(this.title);
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Date");       

    final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
            new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);               

    Series series = new XYChart.Series<Long,Double>();      

    for(DataEntry d : this.entries){
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(d.getTimeStamp(),d.getValue()));
    }

    Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
    lineChart.getData().add(series);


    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
}
```

If this is not possible I would like to know if there is a way to create a LineChart based on parameters, something like

```
new LineChart(int[] x, int[]y)
```

And to be able to integrate it in a scene.

Comment: Your application shouldn't have a parameterized constructor, the launcher won't be able to construct the application as it does not know what values to supply to the constructor.  Where is the input data (title and entries) coming from?  If it is the command line, then you should use [getParameters()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--) within your application (likely in the start() method) to retrieve the command line data.

Comment: Those parameters come from my application, let's say I want to build a chart with all the entries from a given data, I would like if possible to build this chart using something like DataEntryChart("temperature",arrayList)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense though.  The DataEntryChart class you provided extends Application, so that class *is* your application.  Within the DataEntryChart application there is no way to supply the input data for the chart when the application is launched other than via command line arguments, which you currently aren't using.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying, but is there a way to produce such a graph with parameters without command line and put this scene into a stage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a solution working, I use a controller to pass those values as attributes (even if I could do without I just wanted to have this as an attribute to ensure I still have access to it outside of this method)

```
public class GraphListener {

    ArrayList<DataEntry> entries = new ArrayList<DataEntry>();

    @FXML
    private Button updateButton;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> propertiesCombo;
    @FXML
    private Button generateButton;
    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> dataChart;
    @FXML
    private TextArea statsTextArea;

    @FXML
    protected void handleUpdateButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        HBaseClient client = new HBaseClient();
        client.makeConnection();
        ArrayList<String> properties = client.getColumnName("demo");

        propertiesCombo.getItems().clear();
        propertiesCombo.getItems().addAll(properties);

        client.disconnect();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void handleGenerateButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // Retrieving data
        String property = propertiesCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        HBaseClient client = new HBaseClient();
        client.makeConnection();
        this.entries = client.scan("demo", "data", property);
        client.disconnect();

        // Filling the text area
        statsTextArea.clear();
        statsTextArea.appendText("Number of elements : " + handler.numberOfElements()+"\n");
        statsTextArea.appendText("Mean : " + handler.mean()+"\n");
        statsTextArea.appendText("Geometric mean : " + handler.geometricMean()+"\n");
        statsTextArea.appendText("Minimal value : " + handler.min()+"\n");
        statsTextArea.appendText("Maximal value : " + handler.max()+"\n");

        // Generating the graph

        dataChart.setTitle("Evolution of "+property);


        Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName(property);
        ArrayList<Long> timestamps = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (DataEntry d : this.entries) {
            series.getData().add(new Data<Number, Number>(d.getTimeStamp(), d.getValue()));
            timestamps.add(d.getTimeStamp());
        }
        dataChart.getXAxis().setLabel("Timestamp");
        dataChart.getYAxis().setLabel("Values");
        dataChart.getData().add(series);

    }

}
```